# Write into 2 TextBox with a ":" between?

Tags: c#

I have a setting in C# like this:

> 3:20

And I want to transform this setting to 2 TextBox like:

> 3 (TextBox1)
>
> 20 (TextBox2)

I have a problem with the **":"**

Comment: So add a label between the two text boxes and set its text to ":"  (and if you're asking how to break the string into 2 pieces, use `String.Split`.)

Comment: "I have a setting " what exactly do you mean by setting?

Comment: "I have a problem" what exactly do you mean by problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using `String.Split`, this will break the string into an array of strings containing two strings, 3 & 20, then set the text box text accordingly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string setting = "3:20";

        string[] settingsArray = setting.Split(':');

        textBox1.Text = settingsArray[0];
        textBox2.Text = settingsArray[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I got System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Which means that there is either 1, or 0 items in the array. This answer sets you on the right path of how to do this given your initial requirement, if you've changed the data layout - or code - then you'll have to update what I've provided in my answer.

Comment: I used String.Concat to join like this **String.Concat('3', ':', '20')**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here then? Surely if you're concatenating then you can just use the values BEFORE `Concat` is called and set the Textbox text to those values. Nevertheless, I've updated my code sample to use `Concat`.

Comment: No,  I mean like I use Concat for the input, not when I want to split here

Comment: So what's the issue? Can you update your post containing the exact location of where you get `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and possibly a screenshot containing a breakpoint and mouse-over of the variable you're trying to Split.